# Execute two commands using Dockerfile with waits

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-command

I have two commands to run in Dockerfile.
One for run tests and generate logs.
Second one for generate html report after execution of the tests.
My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM golang:1.13   
ADD . /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN go mod download

RUN go get -u "github.com/ains/go-test-html"

CMD ["make", "test", "$URL=", "$INTEGRATION=", "$TESTTYPE=", "$TAGS="]

CMD ["make", "html", "$HTML="]
```

And my docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
version: '3'

services:
  tests:
    image: int-testing-framework:latest
    environment:
      - URL=http://localhost:3000/
      - INTEGRATION=kapten
      - TESTTYPE=contract
      - TAGS=quotes bookings getTrip cancelTrip

  html:
    image: int-testing-framework:latest
    command: make html
    environment:
      - HTML=html
    links:
      - tests
    depends_on:
      - tests
```

And my logs are looks like this:

```
sudo docker-compose up
Creating network "integration_default" with the default driver
Starting integration_tests_1  ... done
Creating integration_html_1 ... done
Attaching to integration_tests_1, integration_html_1
html_1   | Generating HTML report
html_1   | go-test-html logs/[gotest_stdout_file] logs/[gotest_stderr_file] logs/output_file.html
html_1   | Test results written to '/app/logs/output_file.html'
integration_html_1 exited with code 0
tests_1  | Generating HTML report
tests_1  | go-test- logs/[gotest_stdout_file] logs/[gotest_stderr_file] logs/output_file.html
tests_1  | /bin/bash: go-test-: command not found
tests_1  | make: *** [Makefile:14: html] Error 127
integration_tests_1 exited with code 2
```

It's not executing the `tests:` service completely. There should be logs for tests. Any idea of how to execute `tests:` first and generate logs. And after that generate html report?

Answer (score 1):

For this you only want one container.  Have its main command be a shell script that first runs the tests, and then generates the HTML report.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
make test
RC=$?
make html
exit "$RC"
```

```sh
CMD ["./run_tests_and_report.sh"]
```

You could also do something similar by invoking both Makefile targets together

```sh
CMD ["make", "test", "html"]
```

(though that won't generate the report if the tests report a non-zero exit code).

In your current approach there are two issues.  The first is that a Docker container only has one entrypoint and one command, so where your sample Dockerfile has two `CMD` lines, the second is the one that takes effect and both containers are running `make html`.  The second is that Docker Compose has almost no synchronization options, and in particular there is no way to cause the report generation to wait for the test execution to finish (unless you wrote it into a script in your container somehow).